# Adding Azure VM with reserved IP address to Virtual Network

Tags: azure, ipv4, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I have created an Azure Virtual Machine with a static IP address by using the following command:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "be-dmz" -InstanceSize "Standard_D11" -DiskName "be-dmz-be-dmz-0-201508101027470734" | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "Remote Desktop" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort 62062 -LocalPort 3389 | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "PowerShell" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort 5986 -LocalPort 5986 | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "be-dmz" -ReservedIPName "dmz-live" -Location "North Europe"
```

This creates the machine as expected with the reserved IP address but it is in the North Europe location, I want to set this to a virtual network I have called "CloudVNET" but if I enter this in the location it is not correct and errors out.

How can I assign a VM with a static IP address into my virtual network?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
-VNetName "CloudVNET"
```

on New-AzureVM

Answer (score -1):

The storage for the VM needs to be in the same region of the Azure Virtal Network, so you wouldn't be able to assign a VM that exists in one region an address from a VNET that is in another region. You would need to create a new VM in the correct region.

Comment: They are both in same reason